# .NET 8 Server ValidateAuthenticationStateAsync Not Activating

Tags: .net, authentication, asp.net-identity, .net-8.0

The new .NET 8 Server Web App with Identity default build includes `IdentityRevalidatingAuthenticationStateProvider` with `ValidateAuthenticationStateAsync` that should be firing however often `RevalidationInterval` is set to. However, I cannot get it to trigger. I can see the class be initialized on page load but  `ValidateAuthenticationStateAsync` will never fire regardless of the interval time. My code is unchanged from the default outside of the interval.

`IdentityRevalidatingAuthenticationStateProvider.cs`

```
// This is a server-side AuthenticationStateProvider that revalidates the security stamp for the connected user
// every 30 minutes an interactive circuit is connected.
internal sealed class IdentityRevalidatingAuthenticationStateProvider(
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
        IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory,
        IOptions<IdentityOptions> options)
    : RevalidatingServerAuthenticationStateProvider(loggerFactory)
{
    protected override TimeSpan RevalidationInterval => TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);

    protected override async Task<bool> ValidateAuthenticationStateAsync(
        AuthenticationState authenticationState, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Get the user manager from a new scope to ensure it fetches fresh data
        await using var scope = scopeFactory.CreateAsyncScope();
        var userManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
        return await ValidateSecurityStampAsync(userManager, authenticationState.User);
    }

    private async Task<bool> ValidateSecurityStampAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        var user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(principal);
        if (user is null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if (!userManager.SupportsUserSecurityStamp)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            var principalStamp = principal.FindFirstValue(options.Value.ClaimsIdentity.SecurityStampClaimType);
            var userStamp = await userManager.GetSecurityStampAsync(user);
            return principalStamp == userStamp;
        }
    }
}
```

`Program.cs`

```
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents();

builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IdentityUserAccessor>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IdentityRedirectManager>();


builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
    })
    .AddIdentityCookies();
    });

builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, IdentityRevalidatingAuthenticationStateProvider>();
```

I have tried creating new projects with different interactive modes and have created my own `RevalidatingServerAuthenticationStateProvider` using my knowledge from .NET 7 which also did not trigger.

Comment: I have the same issue, @alex did you resolve yours?